# VirtualBox: prohibit taking snapshots or detect restore?

Tags: virtualbox

I need to somehow disable snapshots or at least detect if a snapshot restore has been made on a VM in VirtualBox (need this due to licensing state). From what I understand VirtualBox doesn't have a way to disable snapshots, but is there a way to detect, eg. from the logs, whether a restore has been done?

I tried right-clicking the VM and select Show Log but it was hard to read everything that's there...

Anyone know how I could detect a restore? Even in any creative way? Could I even do something like prohibiting writing to the Snapshots folder in Windows 10?!

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't any ways currently in Virtualbox to disable taking VM snapshots.

Comment: Already kind of knew that.